# Javascript: Referring to this element in if condition

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, if-statement, this, conditional-statements

I am making a script to make a submenu visible as a dropdown when the menu button is hovered (or onmouseover). I made the if condition refer to this.id="menutoggle1" and check if it's true or false.

If true, it should fire off a function with the statement

```
document.getElementById("submenu1").style.display="inherit";
```

It doesn't work, but I assume this has something to do with my if condition. I don't really understand conditions that well, but I hope someone can explain why this is wrong, and maybe even help me fix it.

This is my code;

```
function submenu_show()
{
  if(this.id="menutoggle1" == true)
  {
    document.getElementById("submenu1").style.display="inherit";
  }
}
```

I know another way that I can achieve the result I want, but then I need to write two functions to show and two functions to hide, for all the menu options that are supposed to have submenus, and it is just messy and ugh.

EDIT: I figured I couldn't make it work without dropping my idea completely, so I just went with the other alternative. I also realized that wasn't really that messy after all, when written properly (it is supposed to be used for several drop downs after all).

Here's the code I used eventally;

```
<div id="menubutton1" onmouseover="submenu1_show();" onmouseout="submenu1_hide();"></div>
<div id="submenu1" onmouseover="submenu1_show();" onmouseout="submenu1_hide();"></div>

function submenu1_show()
{document.getElementById("submenu1").style.display="inherit";}
function submenu1_hide()
{document.getElementById("submenu1").style.display="none";}
```

Comment: Before getting into the DOM I'd suggest you take a tour of the basics of JavaScript. You can start at the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript)

Comment: You can do this in CSS without javascript. E.g. http://csswizardry.com/2011/02/creating-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu/

Comment: As soon as I see things like document.getElementBy... and .style.display all I can say is; Use a library like jQuery or similar!

Comment: Everytime I see someone who doesn't know the language use a library I die a little!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current code, *this* is merky. Its certainly not the element's ID. You could find the element in the function.

```
function fnName(){
     var el = document.getElementById("...");
     if(el.id === "something"){ ... }
}
```

If you want to get the function to do this for a particular ID, you could just add a param to the fnName function and pass that param do the doc.getElByID function.

Comment: I guess my plan to make it a bit neater doesn't work after all then. :)
Oh well, I think I might as well just use my alternate method. I'm not really comfortable enough with Javascript to take this answer in properly, though.

Thanks anyway, you were very helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

why not use jQuery to do this for you? With a little bit of CSS and jQuery edits, you can utilize sliding effects and fading effects among other benefits. Look how easy a drop down is with jQuery:

```
$('nav ul li a').hover(
    function() {
        $('nav ul li ul').addClass('over');
    },
    function() {
    $('nav ul li ul').removeClass('over');
    }
);
```

Here is a working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/atomicpages/KVeg2/). I know it doesn't answer your question but I do hope this helps you out a little bit!

Comment: I really want to learn how to use jQuery, but I feel like I should understand Javascript properly first, to be able to fully benefit from the wonders of jQuery. :)